# Calling prepareforSegue from a UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, segue

I am trying to call a `prepareForSegue` function out of `TableViewController` from a button in an `UITableViewCell`.

Can I just call it from the button? Something like:

*TableViewcontroller:*

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "segueExercise") {
            print(segue.identifier)
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
```

*TableViewCell:*

```
@IBAction func exerciseAction(sender: UIButton) {
    ViewController.prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!)
}
```

Would it be too easy, or am I missing something ?

Comment: Thanks. I have only one problem, the `UIButton` only works (calling the next view and passing the data) if the cell is selected first. Is there a way to call the `performSegueWithIdentifier` from the `UIbutton` without selecting the cell first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I passed the index via `UIButton` option `tag` and replaced the `indexPathForSelectedRow`.

Answer (score 7):

`PrepareForSegue` is automatically triggered when you call `performSegueWithIdentifier` (or by Storyboard connecting two UIView CTRL-dragging from first `UIView` to second `UIView`). You can't call it "manually"

Comment: Checking the code againI think I found the problem. `override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) { if (segue.identifier == "segueExercise") { print(segue.identifier) let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! SuggestionDetailViewController if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {` the `prepareForSegue` is indexed with the `indexPathForSelectedRow`. I have already put the index row in the button tag, but I can't manage to get that tag back t the `prepareForSegue`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but you need to override the prepareForSegue() func.  This is used if you are using a 'code only' segue, and can be used to pass values to the new view controller.  For example, this is for a 'Roshambo' game that uses three buttons, one with code only, one with storyboard and code, and one with storyboard only. One prepareForSegue() is used to select the value to be passed based on which button calls for the segue.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
let nextController = segue.destinationViewController as! RoshamboViewController
nextController.opponentValue = self.randomRoshambo()
//determine which segue called prepareForSeque
if (segue.identifier == "choosePaper") {
    nextController.playerValue = "paper"}
else if segue.identifier == "chooseScissors"{
    nextController.playerValue = "scissors"}
```